# FoxPro SQL Code IIF error

Tags: foxpro, iif

I am using querying a FoxPro database and everything is working smoothly apart from the IIF bit. Here is the code..

```
SELECT A.ds_cnref AS 'Stock Ref', A.ds_fact, A.ds_cost, IIF(A.ds_fact='ITM1',A.ds_cost,'B') AS 'Cost Price' FROM DSPROD A
```

The A.ds_fact field produces either ITM1 or ITM2. If its ITM1 then I need to show the A.ds_cost *10 but if its ITM2 then it needs to be A.ds_cost *20

Problem is that it errors out if I try to show the A.ds_cost value (even without the * calculation).

So, this simple A/B result works..

```
IIF(A.ds_fact='ITM1','A','B')
```

but trying to show the ds_cost field errors out.

```
IIF(A.ds_fact='ITM1',A.ds_cost,'B')
```

Would anyone have any ideas please?

Thanks
John

Comment: I've figured it out now. I needed to convert to integer by wrapping the field in INT brackets so..

IIF(A.ds_fact='ITM1',int(A.ds_cost)*10,int(A.ds_cost)*20)

I understand you would need to do that to perform a mathematical calculation on the field but still don't understand why it wouldn't pull in value even without the calculation being applied. Well its working now so hey ho!

Comment: The problem with your original version is that the expression could give you two different result types, depending on the value of A.ds_fact.

Comment: I've seen this type of behavior when the fields aren't the same datatype or precision.  Basically, you are trying to define the field type and precision on the fly.  A cast is the correct way to go, but you could have simply done INT(IIF(A.ds_fact='ITM1', A.ds_cost*10,A.ds_cost*20)) AS 'CostPrice'

Comment: Yes I've noticed this now. We have a program that helps us design and run queries (but it's not very good hence me attempting my own queries) and when I double clicked on a particular field it brought up 3 variations for one field (think it was 'description', 'short description' and something else). But would you know how I would do a query to output, for example, the 'short description'?